# Marshalling pointer to an array in struct from c++ to c#

Tags: c#, arrays, marshalling

How do I convert this expression from C++ to C#?

```
struct MyStruct    
{  
    uint8_t *rcSource;
    uint8_t *rcMask;  
    uint32_t *clientAuthSchemes;  
}
```

The structure is initialised in C++ this way:

```
MyStruct st;
st.rcSource = (uint8_t*) malloc(width*height);
st.rcMask = (uint8_t*) malloc(width*height);
st.clientAuthSchemes = (uint32_t*) malloc(sizeof(uint32_t)*(size+1));
```

Comment: It is too ambiguous, pointers can refer to single values or arrays.  The direct translation is IntPtr but you'll have a hard time initializing them properly if the C++ code doesn't.  Odds to make this work in C# are not very good.

Comment: Bad:(  But could you please describe what can be done to initialize this memory in details?

Comment: I can't, you didn't post any details.

Comment: You can't even initialize this in C++ with the information presented here!

Comment: @HansPassant   rcSource is initialized this way: struct->rcMask = malloc(width * height); rcMask is initialized in the same way. clientAuthSchemes is initialized this way: struct->clientAuthSchemes = (uint32_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t)*(size+1)); ALl this fields are used as 1x arrays.

Comment: Where is the storage allocated C++ or C#. And how does the struct get passed between C++ and C#? What's the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

If those are 1-dimensional arrays, you probably want something like this:

```
struct MyStruct    
{  
    public byte[] rcSource;
    public byte[] rcMask;  
    public uint[] clientAuthSchemes;  
}
```

Initialization:

```
MyStruct st;
st.rcSource = new byte[width*height];
st.rcMask   = new byte[width*height];
st.clientAuthSchemes = new uint[size+1];
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe this is the way:

```
struct MyStruct
{
   sbyte rcSource, rcMask;
   int clientAuthSchemes;
}
```

:)

Comment: No, you created bytes and ints, rather than arrays of unsigned bytes and unsigned ints.

Comment: Agree with Gabe, I also think it must be an array there.